# How can I use open_basedir with php5-fpm & Apache?

Tags: php, apache, open-basedir

I was using `open_basedir` in each Apache virtual host with `mod-php5`.

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/var/www/abc/public_html"
```

Now I have disabled `mod_php5` and configured `fastcgi` and `php5-fpm` and no longer able to use `open_basedir` in virtual hosts. I can still use in `/etc/php5/fpm/php.ini` but I have several virtual hosts and each with different path.

What is the way to add `open_basedir` in virtual hosts while using `php5-fpm`.

Comment: I have the same question. php_admin_value is no longer working in CentOS 8 Apache 2.4.37  virtualhost.